# js-xlsx how to rearrange columns?

Tags: javascript, json, excel, js-xlsx

I am using `js-xlsx` to create an excel file. After doing `.json_to_sheet` I am getting my sheet not with the wanted columns order. for example, I am getting the following order:

```
100 | 200 | 300| 400| a | b | c
```

when `100, 200, 300, 400, a, b, c` are my columns header.

I what to get the following order:

```
a | b | c | 100 | 200 | 300| 400
```

when  `a | b | c` are always constant and the number of the other columns are changing.

**How can I rearrange the columns order?**

**NOTE:**
When used numbers as header the `xlsx` rearrange the columns such that the headers start whit numbers are first and then all the rest. When the headers don't start with numbers you can just order the columns in the `JSON` you save.
One solution is to add a space `' '` before the number and it fixes the problem. but I don't want a space before the number.

Comment: The issue is with js not with xlsx. E.g. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/38218582#38218582. I think the answer below should work...

Comment: that may explain the problem. I will stay with my solution - adding space before the numbers

Answer (score 6):

```
// by default generates 'a,b,c\n1,2,3\n'​
​XLSX​.​utils​.​sheet_to_csv​(​XLSX​.​utils​.​json_to_sheet​(​[​{​a​:​1​,​b​:​2​,​c​:​3​}​]​)​)​

​// pass header:['c','a','b'] to reorder: 'c,a,b\n3,1,2\n'​
​XLSX​.​utils​.​sheet_to_csv​(​XLSX​.​utils​.​json_to_sheet​(​[​{​a​:​1​,​b​:​2​,​c​:​3​}​]​,​ ​{​header​:​[​'c'​,​'a'​,​'b'​]​}​)​)​

​// pass header:['c','b','a'] to reorder: 'c,b,a\n3,2,1\n'​
​XLSX​.​utils​.​sheet_to_csv​(​XLSX​.​utils​.​json_to_sheet​(​[​{​a​:​1​,​b​:​2​,​c​:​3​}​]​, ​{​header​:​[​'c'​,​'b'​,​'a'​]​}​)​)
```

I found this on github issue #738
Check if you can make something out of this. (Something with the 'header' part)

Comment: it doesn't help, when used numbers as header the ```xlsx``` rearrange the columns such that the headers start whit numbers are first and then all the rest. when the headers don't start with numbers you can just order the columns in the ```JSON``` you save

Comment: Can you expand on why it doesn't help ? Passing `["a", "b", "c", "100", "200", "300", "400"]` to the `header` option should do what you want.

Comment: I did the same, but when I open it with excel it is not in the same order - the numbers are first